# Select some columns instead of select * with SubSonic 3

Tags: subsonic3

I'm using SubSonic 3 as my OR mapper in the project. My problem is that the query SubSonic generates for `select` and other operations is like:

```
var repo = GetRepo();
var results = repo.GetAll();
```

And this would make `select *` from the entity, but I have to select only `Id` and `Title` from the table. I don't have permission to `select *` on the table

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much to go off of and you probably solved this problem already but just in case someone else has the same question, here's my 2 cents.

If you just wanted to select `Id` and `Title` you could do one of the following.

I'm guessing you're using ActiveRecord.

```
//results in a list of anonymous objects with Id and Title
var results = (from r in YourTable.All() select new { Id = r.Id, Title = r.Title }).ToList();
```

If you're using AdvancedTemplate, then you could do

```
//create an instance of the db schema
var repo = new SubSonic.AdvancedTemplate.YourDatabase();

//results in a list of anonymous objects with Id and Title
var results = (from r in repo.YourTable select new { Id = r.Id, Title = r.Title }).ToList();
```